# React Native block/close phone dialing

Tags: android, ios, react-native, call

I have been studying react native for a few days, and I would like to make a small application that blocks dialing to certain phone numbers.

So I would like to know if there is any way of using react native, to end/block a phone dialing?

I'm using this package to detect calls

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-call-detection

Comment: how to you fix it?